# A rapid question on $f(R)$ gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, modified-gravity

Is it possible to construct a $f(R)$ where,

$$f(R) = \alpha R \tag{1} ?$$

I'm asking this for two reasons: $1)$ I'm quite a freshman on modified theories of gravity and $2)$ Most of the times I see the papers using $f(R) = \alpha R^{2}$ as the simplest model.

Comment: How would that differ from GR?

Comment: Since we have a final master equation as: $\alpha G = 8\pi T$

Comment: But ok, I think that the divergence of $\alpha G_{ab}$ is still $0$, isn't? Also, I have a undergraduate question where the professor asked a proof that $R_{ab} = 4\pi G [\alpha T_{ab} +(1-\alpha)Tg_{ab}]$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ have the same newtonian limit as GR, maybe $(1)$ and this proof are related...i don't know.

Comment: See my answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/611646/constraints-on-the-einstein-hilbert-action/611665#611665

Answer (score 2):

Remember that if you don't geometrize your units, the field equations are actually

$G_{\mu\nu} = \frac{8\pi G}{c^4} T_{\mu\nu}$

And that factor of $\frac{8\pi G}{c^4}$ was specifically chosen so that in the low-speed, low-energy limit, we would recover the Poisson equation for the Newtonian gravitational potential,

$\nabla^2 \phi = 4\pi G \rho$

So, like the commenter points out, what you're talking about is really just GR before the constant has been fixed to match Newtonian gravity, ie. with $\alpha \ne 1$ it is a valid theory but experimentally inaccurate from the outset.

Comment: So, in order to study properly $f(R)$ theories, I must to consider $f(R) = \alpha R^{n}$ with $n>1$?

Comment: You could still in principle get "the right equations" from $f(R) = \alpha R$.  You'd just have to define $T_{\mu \nu}$ as something like $\alpha^{-1} \delta \mathcal{L}_\text{mat}/\delta g^{\mu \nu}$ in order to match the Newtonian limit.  (With appropriate factors of $\sqrt{-g}$ thrown in, of course.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert  I see. But my question is more like: given the EFE in $f(R)$:

$f'(R)R_{ab}-\frac{1}{2}f(R)g_{ab}-\nabla_{a}\nabla_{b}f'(R)+\square f'(R)g_{ab} = 8\pi T_{ab}$

Where f' is $\frac{df}{dR}$ (a derivation with respect to ricci scalar). For the particular case $f(R) = \alpha R$ differs from GR totaly? Since the whole calculation gives: $G_{ab} = 8\pi \alpha T_{ab}$ returning the constans we would have: $G_{ab} = \frac{ 8\pi \alpha G}{c^{4}} T_{ab}$

Comment: @M.N.Raia Take a look at [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F(R)_gravity#Observational_tests).  In general you have $f(R) = a_0 + a_1 R + a_2 R^2 + ...$, but $a_0$ and $a_1$ are fixed by the accelerated expansion of the universe, and the Newtonian limit, respectively.

Comment: @M.N.Raia:  If you put $f(R) = \alpha R$ into that equation, you just end up with $\alpha G_{ab} = \frac{1}{8 \pi} T_{ab}$.  This effectively corresponds to a rescaling of Newton's constant $G$, but that's really just equivalent to choosing a different unit of mass.  So it's not a physically distinct model.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Nice, now I got it. Consider write a proper answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Wow, I see, so the underlying point is that scaling the Lagrangian does not change its stationary solutions, hence doesn't change the real content of the theory.  Right?  Guess I should have left this one to the experts :)